# getpass ввод спецсимволов в терминале Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

```
import getpass  
pwd = getpass.getpass('Ведите пароль: ')  
print(pwd)
```

При использовании getpass для скрытия вводимого пароля в терминале Visual Studio Code столкнулся с проблемой:
если ввести пароль содержащий спецсимволы, то на выходе получим введенный пароль без некоторых символов.
Например:
ввод: @#$^&*{}|qwerty
вывод: *qwerty

Как этого избежать?

Comment: В какой среде это происходит? У меня все символы выводятся.

Comment: Я также не могу воспроизвести ваши результаты, какая у вас ос и версия питона?

Comment: В Google Colab всё нормально печатает

Comment: Windows 10
Python 3.9.2 
Visual Studio Code

Comment: Попробовал и на рабочем и на домашнем ПК. Результат один и тот же

Comment: за приделами VSC, например в cmd выполняется нормально.
Отредактирую вопрос

Comment: так и не разобрался...  

Files: Encoding = UTF-8  и 
Terminal > Integrated: Detect Locale = auto  

что еще хоть как-то может быть связано с проблемой не нашел..  
По итогу сбросил настройки VSC и все нормализовалось